# AngularJS $setValidity is adding $errors to form that I can't get rid of

Tags: angularjs

I'm really stuck on an issue caused by this line:    `ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);`

```
.directive('formMatch', ['$parse', '$timeout', '$log', function ($parse, $timeout, $log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A'
      ,priority: 2
      ,require: 'ngModel'
      ,link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue)) || $parse(attrs.match)(scope) === ctrl.$modelValue;
        }, function(currentValue) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

It is causing the form that this input is contained within to have $error values... Ex.

```
email: false
match: Array[1]
required: Array[2]
```

and even after `ctrl.$setValidity('match', true);` is called those errors are not going away.  But if I simply comment out that line, the form validates and works properly again.  It almost seems like somehow the "ctrl" var is referencing the form at times when this line is called, but that seems impossible to me that it could reference both the input and the form...

Is there anyway to do a form.$updateValidity()?   Not saying that this would help, but it is something I would like to try since, as I say, each individual form input has is $valid === true.

Comment: the `$setValidity` of `ngModel` will propagate state up into parent forms automatically.

Comment: Are there more than one input that has the `formMatch` directive? May be provide a plunker would be helpful.

Comment: What version of angular.js are you running?

Comment: AngularJS Version 1.2.20 - It does seem to propagate state, but it would be super nice if it propagated when it is valid :)